# How to get content of cached resources of a web page

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I need to get content of cached `XHR` requests made to some server using `JS` assuming  **I can't make a fetch request to server again**. Just for example, I need to load content of a `model.json...` file from `https://data.worldbank.org/indicator`.

[image]

Comment: what you need is not clear, if you want to get the JSON and cache it in Javascript then you can use html5 Local storage http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @VoiceOfTheRain, I need to load `model.json`, which is cached in my browser and which I can see in `Network` tab of Chrome, as a local file to my PC or to a `JS variable`.

Comment: @VoiceOfTheRain, any ideas?